# Can we programmatically configure Chrome?

Tags: java, javascript, google-chrome, primefaces

I'm trying to enable the option "Ask for download location" on Chrome programmatically, since my client wants to have a browse window to pick the download location. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

No. Websites cannot change a user's browser preferences for them.